# Runtime polymorphism overhead in Julia

Tags: performance, polymorphism, julia

I understand that Julia heavily relies on just-in-time static type derivation (essentially all code needs to be thought of as c++ templates). I also get that this means there is no run-time overhead when using a single algorithm on objects of different type as long as those types are known at compile-time.

When it comes to run-time polymorphism I am less clear on how things work. Say we have the following situation:

```
abstract Shape

type Circle <: Shape
    radius::Float64
end

type Square <: Shape
    width::Float64
end

dist(x::Circle, y::Circle) = ...
dist(x::Circle, y::Square) = ...
dist(x::Square, y::Circle) = ...
dist(x::Square, y::Square) = ...


s = get_shape()
t = get_shape()
a = dist(s,t)
```

Here, `get_shape` can return either circles or squares, based on e.g. user input. In c++, dispatch would simply take a virtual table lookup. How does this work in Julia? What is the mechanism behind multiple dispatch? Is it significantly more expensive then virtual table lookup? Is there any benefit from deriving both `Square` and `Circle` from the same abstract type, or is this completely irrelevant in the context of run-time dispatching?

EDT: Running @code_warntype on this example gives:

```
Variables:
  s::Union{Circle,Square}
  t::Union{Circle,Square}

Body:
  begin  # none, line 2:
      s = (Main.get_shape)()::Union{Circle,Square} # none, line 3:
      t = (Main.get_shape)()::Union{Circle,Square} # none, line 4:
      return (Main.dist)(s::Union{Circle,Square},t::Union{Circle,Square})::ASCIIString
  end::ASCIIString
```

So the compiler is not completely clueless about the type of s and t. Is this knowledge used to expedite dispatching when calling `dist`?

Comment: If I had to guess myself in this case (where the compile time type is a Union of composite types), I would say that the compiler generates four virtual tables (for the four possible combinations of types) and that subsequently run-time dispatch is comparable in speed to c++'. Does that sound about right?

Answer (score 12):

When you have multiple methods for the same function, julia uses method lookup via type intersection (matching the types of the arguments to the types in the signature) to determine which method to call. If the types can be inferred, then that calculation can be performed when the code is being compiled. By doing the lookup ahead of time, it doesn't have to perform type intersection at run time, and this gives the best performance.

When the types are not predictable, then julia has to figure out which method to dispatch to at runtime. This can sometimes be a bottleneck on the runtime, if the called function is doing a trivial amount of work. (When it's doing a lot of work, the lookup is basically inconsequential for performance).

It's a slightly more complicated problem for julia than OOP languages, because the correct method depends on all the arguments, not just the first.

Comment: What currently is it doing in that case?  For example, if it knows that there are only two possible types, and all the other types are known, shouldn't it be able to do one simple comparison, and branch to code optimized for one type or the other, with almost no extra overhead, but I don't believe that's currently the case.  In this case, with 4 possible combinations of types, it should be able to pick an optimized method with just two comparisons.

Comment: ScottJones is touching on exactly the type of implementation details I am interested in to make well-informed decisions on performance trade-offs. If Julia has to perform intricate type identification before dispatch, it seems to me that `get_shape` should return an enum value corresponding to the returned type. I then can use this type id in a nested `if` (2x2 branches) block to do cheap dispatching manually. However, I am still hoping the Julia JIT compiler will create such an `if` block in my stead. Any chance of that happening?

Comment: I don't think that the Julia compiler will currently create such an `if` block, but it seems reasonable that it will some day, at least when there's a limited number of cases.But instead of returning an enum value, you can check the type with `isa` in your `if` block.

Comment: I'm not certain. This is definitely on the table, and perhaps much of it is implemented, but I don't think it's fully in place yet. Relevant performance benchmarks were posted in https://groups.google.com/d/msg/julia-users/jUMu9A3QKQQ/qjgVWr7vAwAJ.

Comment: Another similar performance issue is how is dispatch handled when you have a partially parameterized type, say if a type takes 3 parameters, but only the first one is specified in the arguments to a method. Will it have to do runtime dispatching?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but if somebody is interested in numbers I found a little [benchmark](https://github.com/cdsousa/SingleDispatchJuliaVsCXX). As it turns out, currently (1.1) runtime polymorphism using abstract types is abysmally slow (30x vs static dispatch and 6x vs C++ virtual function calls).

Comment: How funny is when one is searching for something about a topic and follows a link that goes to something written/said by themselves? I wrote that code long ago :)    One thing to take into account is that having an array of a limited number of different types (I don't know the limit but I suspect it is not very high) whose element type is a Union of that types, effectively reduces the dispatch overhead to around the same of C++ virtual calls (it's the last time of the Julia test).

Comment: Related: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/update-on-single-dispatch-benchmark-comparison-to-c/7283